# OpenCL memory leaks and errors even after releasing everything with clRelease*()

Tags: c, memory-leaks, opencl, valgrind

I've written a really simple OpenCL program that just adds up two arrays. It works correctly, however if I run it with Valgrind I'm getting lots of memory leaks even after I release everything using clRelease*. I am also getting a `Mismatched free() / delete / delete[]` Valgrind error when have `clReleaseProgram(program)` in my source code. To be clear I'm getting memory leaks regardless of if I have that line or not, but that line also gives me the error.

I've included the `main.c` and `kernel.cl` source code files as well as the Valgrind output I get with the `clReleaseProgram(program)` line in main.c

I don't know if this is relevant but I am using AMD's ROCM OpenCL implementation and am using version 1.2, and this is running on a Radeon RX 5700XT graphics card. OS is Ubuntu 20.04.

I'd really appreciate any advice!

```
// Simple test OpenCL program that adds two arrays

// Define OpenCL version
#define CL_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION 120

#include <CL/cl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


// Main program
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // Create all three arrays needed
    float arr1[] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0};
    float arr2[] = {10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0};
    float arr3[4]; 
    
    // Initialize platform id structure
    cl_int err;
    cl_platform_id platform;
    err = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform, NULL);

    // Initialize device id structure
    cl_device_id device;
    err = clGetDeviceIDs(platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &device, NULL);

    // Initialize context
    cl_context context = clCreateContext(NULL, 1, &device, NULL, NULL, &err);

    // Determine file size of kernel source file
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("kernel.cl", "r");
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    long int src_size = ftell(fp);
    rewind(fp);

    // Read kernel source file into buffer
    char *buf = malloc(sizeof(char) * (src_size + 1));
    fread(buf, sizeof(char), src_size, fp);
    buf[src_size] = '\0';

    // Create the program
    cl_program program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1, (const char **) &buf, NULL, &err);
    free(buf);

    // Build the program
    const char options[] = "-cl-std=CL1.2 -D MULT=2";
    err = clBuildProgram(program, 1, &device, options, NULL, NULL);

    // Create command queue
    cl_command_queue queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device, CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE, &err);

    // Create kernel
    const char kernel_name[] = "test_kernel";
    cl_kernel kernel = clCreateKernel(program, kernel_name, &err);

    // Create the memory objects
    cl_mem arr1_mem = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, 4 * sizeof(float), NULL, &err);
    cl_mem arr2_mem = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, 4 * sizeof(float), NULL, &err);
    cl_mem arr3_mem = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, 4 * sizeof(float), NULL, &err);

    // Write the input arrays into the input mem objects
    err = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queue, arr1_mem, CL_TRUE, 0, 4 * sizeof(float), arr1, 0, NULL, NULL);
    err = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queue, arr2_mem, CL_TRUE, 0, 4 * sizeof(float), arr2, 0, NULL, NULL);

    // Set the kernel arguments
    err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(arr1_mem), &arr1_mem);
    err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(arr2_mem), &arr2_mem);
    err = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(arr3_mem), &arr3_mem);

    // Execute kernel
    size_t gws[] = {4};
    err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 1, NULL, gws, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);

    // Read the output array into the output mem object
    err = clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue, arr3_mem, CL_TRUE, 0, 4 * sizeof(float), arr3, 0, NULL, NULL);

    // Print the output
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        printf("%f\n", arr3[i]);
    }

    // Release all OpenCL objects
    clReleaseMemObject(arr1_mem);
    clReleaseMemObject(arr2_mem);
    clReleaseMemObject(arr3_mem);
    clReleaseKernel(kernel);
    clReleaseCommandQueue(queue);
    clReleaseProgram(program); // This line causes Mismatched free / delete[] / delete valgrind error
    clReleaseContext(context);

    return 0;
}
```

```
// Test OpenCL kernel
__kernel void test_kernel(__constant float *arr1, __constant float *arr2, __global float *arr3) {
    // Get the index into the arrays
    int index = get_global_id(0);

    // Sum arr1 + arr2 and store in arr3
    arr3[index] = arr1[index] + arr2[index];
}
```

```
ivy@ubuntu-main:~/cl_test$ valgrind ./a.out
==10340== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==10340== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==10340== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==10340== Command: ./a.out
==10340== 
==10340== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x59c9d000, 0x159e9e000) (noaccess)
11.000000
13.000000
15.000000
17.000000
==10340== Mismatched free() / delete / delete []
==10340==    at 0x483CFBF: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==10340==    by 0x542B8C0: rocr::amd::hsa::loader::AmdHsaCodeLoader::DestroyExecutable(rocr::amd::hsa::loader::Executable*) (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/lib/libhsa-runtime64.so.1.2.30700)
==10340==    by 0x5407ECF: rocr::HSA::hsa_executable_destroy(hsa_executable_s) (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/lib/libhsa-runtime64.so.1.2.30700)
==10340==    by 0x5159C13: roc::Program::~Program() (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/opencl/lib/libamdocl64.so)
==10340==    by 0x515A606: roc::LightningProgram::~LightningProgram() (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/opencl/lib/libamdocl64.so)
==10340==    by 0x5106B22: amd::Program::~Program() (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/opencl/lib/libamdocl64.so)
==10340==    by 0x5106D28: amd::Program::~Program() (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/opencl/lib/libamdocl64.so)
==10340==    by 0x51006C5: amd::ReferenceCountedObject::release() (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/opencl/lib/libamdocl64.so)
==10340==    by 0x50DACB3: clReleaseProgram (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/opencl/lib/libamdocl64.so)
==10340==    by 0x1099A3: main (main.c:92)
==10340==  Address 0xe3634c0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 42 alloc'd
==10340==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==10340==    by 0x4B0750E: strdup (strdup.c:42)
==10340==    by 0x54348A3: rocr::amd::hsa::loader::ExecutableImpl::LoadCodeObject(hsa_agent_s, hsa_code_object_s, unsigned long, char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, hsa_loaded_code_object_s*) (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/lib/libhsa-runtime64.so.1.2.30700)
==10340==    by 0x5434F52: rocr::amd::hsa::loader::ExecutableImpl::LoadCodeObject(hsa_agent_s, hsa_code_object_s, char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, hsa_loaded_code_object_s*) (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/lib/libhsa-runtime64.so.1.2.30700)
==10340==    by 0x5408460: rocr::HSA::hsa_executable_load_agent_code_object(hsa_executable_s, hsa_agent_s, hsa_code_object_reader_s, char const*, hsa_loaded_code_object_s*) (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/lib/libhsa-runtime64.so.1.2.30700)
==10340==    by 0x5159FBF: roc::LightningProgram::setKernels(amd::option::Options*, void*, unsigned long) (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/opencl/lib/libamdocl64.so)
==10340==    by 0x5153358: device::Program::linkImplLC(amd::option::Options*) (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/opencl/lib/libamdocl64.so)
==10340==    by 0x5153ABC: device::Program::build(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, char const*, amd::option::Options*) (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/opencl/lib/libamdocl64.so)
==10340==    by 0x5108F31: amd::Program::build(std::vector<amd::Device*, std::allocator<amd::Device*> > const&, char const*, void (*)(_cl_program*, void*), void*, bool, bool) (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/opencl/lib/libamdocl64.so)
==10340==    by 0x50DAF42: clBuildProgram (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/opencl/lib/libamdocl64.so)
==10340==    by 0x1096B5: main (main.c:51)
==10340== 
==10340== 
==10340== HEAP SUMMARY:
==10340==     in use at exit: 991,949 bytes in 4,653 blocks
==10340==   total heap usage: 576,804 allocs, 572,151 frees, 246,308,729 bytes allocated
==10340== 
==10340== LEAK SUMMARY:
==10340==    definitely lost: 67,584 bytes in 1 blocks
==10340==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10340==      possibly lost: 7,692 bytes in 66 blocks
==10340==    still reachable: 916,673 bytes in 4,586 blocks
==10340==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10340== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==10340== 
==10340== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==10340== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Edit: Output when running: `Valgrind --leak-check=full ./a.out`
I omitted the beginning of the `Valgrind` output because its exactly the same as above. I also omitted most of the middle output because all the errors look essentially the same, and there are too many of them to fit in this post.

```
... Same output here as above ...


==4996== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4996==     in use at exit: 991,947 bytes in 4,653 blocks
==4996==   total heap usage: 575,705 allocs, 571,052 frees, 246,015,102 bytes allocated
==4996== 
==4996== 4 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 7 of 2,212
==4996==    at 0x483B723: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4996==    by 0x483E017: realloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4996==    by 0x5B27783: _fmm_map_to_gpu.isra.8 (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/lib/libhsakmt.so.1.0.30700)
==4996==    by 0x5B28B57: fmm_map_to_gpu (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/lib/libhsakmt.so.1.0.30700)
==4996==    by 0x5B2950F: fmm_init_process_apertures (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/lib/libhsakmt.so.1.0.30700)
==4996==    by 0x5B2CD2B: hsaKmtOpenKFD (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/lib/libhsakmt.so.1.0.30700)
==4996==    by 0x5401368: rocr::AMD::Load() (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/lib/libhsa-runtime64.so.1.2.30700)
==4996==    by 0x542440D: rocr::core::Runtime::Acquire() (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/lib/libhsa-runtime64.so.1.2.30700)
==4996==    by 0x54027C9: rocr::HSA::hsa_init() (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/lib/libhsa-runtime64.so.1.2.30700)
==4996==    by 0x5135C84: roc::Device::init() (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/opencl/lib/libamdocl64.so)
==4996==    by 0x50F832E: amd::Device::init() (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/opencl/lib/libamdocl64.so)
==4996==    by 0x5102525: amd::Runtime::init() (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/opencl/lib/libamdocl64.so)
==4996== 
==4996== 4 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 8 of 2,212
==4996==    at 0x483B723: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4996==    by 0x483E017: realloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4996==    by 0x5B27783: _fmm_map_to_gpu.isra.8 (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/lib/libhsakmt.so.1.0.30700)
==4996==    by 0x5B28B57: fmm_map_to_gpu (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/lib/libhsakmt.so.1.0.30700)
==4996==    by 0x5B2C520: hsaKmtMapMemoryToGPU (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/lib/libhsakmt.so.1.0.30700)
==4996==    by 0x5B2F29B: allocate_exec_aligned_memory_gpu (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/lib/libhsakmt.so.1.0.30700)
==4996==    by 0x5B25679: hsaKmtCreateEvent (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/lib/libhsakmt.so.1.0.30700)
==4996==    by 0x5414E62: rocr::core::InterruptSignal::CreateEvent(_HSA_EVENTTYPE, bool) (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/lib/libhsa-runtime64.so.1.2.30700)
==4996==    by 0x541FD00: rocr::core::Runtime::BindVmFaultHandler() (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/lib/libhsa-runtime64.so.1.2.30700)
==4996==    by 0x5424427: rocr::core::Runtime::Acquire() (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/lib/libhsa-runtime64.so.1.2.30700)
==4996==    by 0x54027C9: rocr::HSA::hsa_init() (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/lib/libhsa-runtime64.so.1.2.30700)
==4996==    by 0x5135C84: roc::Device::init() (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/opencl/lib/libamdocl64.so)


... Lots of similar repeating errors here ...


==4996== 720 bytes in 3 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 2,165 of 2,212
==4996==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4996==    by 0x5B262DF: vm_create_and_init_object (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/lib/libhsakmt.so.1.0.30700)
==4996==    by 0x5B265EC: fmm_allocate_memory_object (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/lib/libhsakmt.so.1.0.30700)
==4996==    by 0x5B28219: fmm_allocate_host (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/lib/libhsakmt.so.1.0.30700)
==4996==    by 0x5B2B9FA: hsaKmtAllocMemory (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/lib/libhsakmt.so.1.0.30700)
==4996==    by 0x53F0E31: rocr::AMD::MemoryRegion::Allocate(unsigned long&, unsigned int, void**) const (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/lib/libhsa-runtime64.so.1.2.30700)
==4996==    by 0x541C4C2: std::_Function_handler<void* (unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned int), rocr::core::Runtime::RegisterAgent(rocr::core::Agent*)::{lambda(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned int)#1}>::_M_invoke(std::_Any_data const&, unsigned long&&, std::_Any_data const&, unsigned int&&) (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/lib/libhsa-runtime64.so.1.2.30700)
==4996==    by 0x53DF22E: rocr::AMD::GpuAgent::AssembleShader(char const*, rocr::AMD::GpuAgent::AssembleTarget, void*&, unsigned long&) const (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/lib/libhsa-runtime64.so.1.2.30700)
==4996==    by 0x53D39B2: rocr::AMD::BlitKernel::Initialize(rocr::core::Agent const&) (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/lib/libhsa-runtime64.so.1.2.30700)
==4996==    by 0x53DD58A: std::_Function_handler<rocr::core::Blit* (), rocr::AMD::GpuAgent::InitDma()::{lambda()#3}>::_M_invoke(std::_Any_data const&) (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/lib/libhsa-runtime64.so.1.2.30700)
==4996==    by 0x53DD2F9: rocr::AMD::GpuAgent::DmaCopy(void*, void const*, unsigned long) (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/lib/libhsa-runtime64.so.1.2.30700)
==4996==    by 0x53ED80A: rocr::(anonymous namespace)::RegionMemory::Freeze() (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/lib/libhsa-runtime64.so.1.2.30700)
==4996== 
==4996== 1,200 bytes in 5 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 2,173 of 2,212
==4996==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4996==    by 0x5B262DF: vm_create_and_init_object (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/lib/libhsakmt.so.1.0.30700)
==4996==    by 0x5B265EC: fmm_allocate_memory_object (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/lib/libhsakmt.so.1.0.30700)
==4996==    by 0x5B28219: fmm_allocate_host (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/lib/libhsakmt.so.1.0.30700)
==4996==    by 0x5B2B9FA: hsaKmtAllocMemory (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/lib/libhsakmt.so.1.0.30700)
==4996==    by 0x53F0E31: rocr::AMD::MemoryRegion::Allocate(unsigned long&, unsigned int, void**) const (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/lib/libhsa-runtime64.so.1.2.30700)
==4996==    by 0x541C4C2: std::_Function_handler<void* (unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned int), rocr::core::Runtime::RegisterAgent(rocr::core::Agent*)::{lambda(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned int)#1}>::_M_invoke(std::_Any_data const&, unsigned long&&, std::_Any_data const&, unsigned int&&) (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/lib/libhsa-runtime64.so.1.2.30700)
==4996==    by 0x542B8D5: rocr::core::Shared<rocr::core::SharedSignal, rocr::core::SharedSignalPool_t>::Shared(rocr::core::SharedSignalPool_t*, int) (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/lib/libhsa-runtime64.so.1.2.30700)
==4996==    by 0x542921E: rocr::core::LocalSignal::LocalSignal(long, bool) (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/lib/libhsa-runtime64.so.1.2.30700)
==4996==    by 0x5414EE8: rocr::core::InterruptSignal::InterruptSignal(long, _HsaEvent*) (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/lib/libhsa-runtime64.so.1.2.30700)
==4996==    by 0x5410E85: rocr::AMD::hsa_amd_signal_create(long, unsigned int, hsa_agent_s const*, unsigned long, hsa_signal_s*) (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/lib/libhsa-runtime64.so.1.2.30700)
==4996==    by 0x513B727: roc::VirtualGPU::initPool(unsigned long, unsigned int) (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/opencl/lib/libamdocl64.so)
==4996== 
==4996== 67,584 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2,209 of 2,212
==4996==    at 0x483B7F3: malloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4996==    by 0xA977E83: RegisterHandlers() (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/lib/libamd_comgr.so.1.6.30700)
==4996==    by 0xA9787EB: llvm::sys::RemoveFileOnSignal(llvm::StringRef, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*) (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/lib/libamd_comgr.so.1.6.30700)
==4996==    by 0x8F2BC0E: clang::CompilerInstance::createOutputFile(llvm::StringRef, std::error_code&, bool, bool, llvm::StringRef, llvm::StringRef, bool, bool, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*) (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/lib/libamd_comgr.so.1.6.30700)
==4996==    by 0x8F2BFD2: clang::CompilerInstance::createOutputFile(llvm::StringRef, bool, bool, llvm::StringRef, llvm::StringRef, bool, bool) (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/lib/libamd_comgr.so.1.6.30700)
==4996==    by 0x8F2C39E: clang::CompilerInstance::createDefaultOutputFile(bool, llvm::StringRef, llvm::StringRef) (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/lib/libamd_comgr.so.1.6.30700)
==4996==    by 0x77F3913: GetOutputStream(clang::CompilerInstance&, llvm::StringRef, clang::BackendAction) (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/lib/libamd_comgr.so.1.6.30700)
==4996==    by 0x77F959A: clang::CodeGenAction::CreateASTConsumer(clang::CompilerInstance&, llvm::StringRef) (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/lib/libamd_comgr.so.1.6.30700)
==4996==    by 0x8F6D175: clang::FrontendAction::CreateWrappedASTConsumer(clang::CompilerInstance&, llvm::StringRef) (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/lib/libamd_comgr.so.1.6.30700)
==4996==    by 0x8F70865: clang::FrontendAction::BeginSourceFile(clang::CompilerInstance&, clang::FrontendInputFile const&) (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/lib/libamd_comgr.so.1.6.30700)
==4996==    by 0x8F2F079: clang::CompilerInstance::ExecuteAction(clang::FrontendAction&) (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/lib/libamd_comgr.so.1.6.30700)
==4996==    by 0x743641A: clang::ExecuteCompilerInvocation(clang::CompilerInstance*) (in /opt/rocm-3.7.0/lib/libamd_comgr.so.1.6.30700)
==4996== 
==4996== LEAK SUMMARY:
==4996==    definitely lost: 67,584 bytes in 1 blocks
==4996==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4996==      possibly lost: 7,692 bytes in 66 blocks
==4996==    still reachable: 916,671 bytes in 4,586 blocks
==4996==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4996== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==4996== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==4996== 
==4996== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==4996== ERROR SUMMARY: 56 errors from 56 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug you should be reporting against the rocm project.

Comment: @pmdj Would the proper way of doing this be [here](https://github.com/RadeonOpenCompute/rocm/issues)? And could I link this stackoverflow question or should I ask it again from scratch there? I don't want to annoy the devs lol.

Comment: Looks like that's the right place, note how there are some other reports about valgrind errors. Make sure you check if anyone has reported the specific error you've encountered, and see if you can reduce your code sample down any further and still get the error(s) before you post. I'd post the repro code there, I don't think linking to Stack Overflow is likely to be useful to anyone.

Comment: @pmdj Ok I'll do that then. This code is actually already the simplest example I could come up with to reproduce the errors in my main gaussian blur program. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using 'standard' libstdc++ and libc, then in your case, a mismatch strdup / delete (rather than strdup / free) should not pose a problem. This is because libstdc++ `new` simply calls `malloc`, and `delete` calls `free`. On the other hand, if ever you use a replacement `delete` that is *not* based on `free`, then your application will very likely crash horribly.

For the memory leaks, you need to run `memcheck` with `--leak-check=full`, as it says near the end of the Valgrind output.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. The allocation and de allocation is handled by ROCM code, so if I am understanding you correctly as long as their code is using `new` and `delete` to call `malloc` and `free` there shouldn't be a problem? My program is producing the correct output so I assume that means its not "crashing horribly?" Also I added the `Valgrind --leak-check=full` output but as you can see all the origins of all the leaks start within ROCM code, so I'm not really sure what I'm supposed to do on my end of the code. Any advice?